# uml extension use cases can terminate the flow of events of its base use cases?

Tags: uml, use-case

Im modeling a base use case and its extension use case. Ive been reading that when a condition is meet on the base use case the extension use case is triggered and executed, and after the execution of the extension use case the base use case is resumed. **My doubt is if the extension use case can terminate the flow of the base use case insted of resuming it?**

In the book **"Writing Effective Use Cases"** theres an example of ATM in which the base use case is "use ATM" and the extension use case is 
"use card from another bank". On this context in my opinion sounds correctly to finish the flow from the extension use case (when the user doesnt accept the charge for using the ATM of external bank)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, basically any exception can terminate a use case at any time. So the answer is simply "yes, it can".

However, although Cockburn is the Pope of Use Cases, he's more a technician than an analyst. Use cases are about added value. A UC "Use ATM" is more than questionable. It does not tell anything about the use. You could use the ATM to tie it to Cockburn's feet and drown him in the nearest sea. Further, extend/include should simply be avoided since they do not add good value (sic!) to use case synthesis but seduce people to perform functional decomposition. There are only rare cases where they make sense. And even there you can live without them.

I'd recommend to rather read Bittner/Spence. In my opinion they got it spot on. Keep Cockburn with the emphasis on "writing", but read Bittner/Spence to "understand".

Comment: thanks a lot dude for your comment.. before accepting the answer im just waiting for some more ideas so maybe Cockburn will complete the answer with some include use cases to scape from the sea :)

Comment: No hurry. I still remember I had a hard time understand UCs when I started with UML.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts to keep such extensions accurate and easy to read I ended up wrapping them into "System validates that some condition is fulfilled". In the book this situation is not really given is a full use case (or I found a wrong one) so I will write example of proposed approach from scratch.

---

### UC_01 User withdraws money from ATM

Level: User goal

## Main success scenario

```
...
3. User provides amount.
4. User confirms operation.
5. [UC_02 System validates transaction].
6. System performs transaction.
...
9. System returns the card.
```

## Failure flow A

Precondition: Validation failed at step 5.

```
6. System displays error message to User.
7. The use case continues from step 9.
```

---

### UC_02 System validates transaction

Level: subfunction

```
...
3. [UC_06 System validates that user agrees with processing fee].
4. [UC_07 System validates that there is enough money on the account].
...
```

## Failure flow D

Precondition: Validation failed at step 3.

```
4. The use case terminates.
```

---

P.S. 9 steps is normally too much for a single use case, I put them only to emphasize.